# What does an '_' in django url do?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

what does an '_' in django url means like,

```
url(_(r'^mylink/'), include('link5.urls')),
```

_ plus a string should be an error but one public app is using such construct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is often a shortcut for a gettext function that will produce a localized version of the string.  It's unusual to do it for URLs, but it's documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns

At the top of the file you might find something like:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

Comment: I tried _(r'^mylink/') with import gettext, why a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Comment: Something else is going on. There's no way to know what without seeing the whole file and error report.

Comment: @djangoman In an interactive shell, `_` saves the return value of the last line executed inside the console, which may override the function IIRC. Maybe that's what you saw the first time?

Comment: @knbk good info I gorgot about that _ saves return value of last eval.